# printf all characters in a string using HEX i.e. printf("%X", string.c_str())

Tags: c++, printf

I'm on an embedded Linux platform which uses C++ but also `printf` for logging.

I receive data in `string` type - `"\241\242"` -  but they're unprintable characters.

On the sender side, I type in a hex number in string format i.e. `"A1A2"` but the sender encodes it as the number `0xA1A2` so on the receiver, I cannot use `printf("%s", thing.c_str())`

I can use `printf("%X")` but only for one character at a time in a for loop `printf("%X", thing[i])`. The for-loop would be ok except that since I need to use the logging macro, each hex character comes out on a separate line.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to use ONE `printf("%X")` to print all the characters in the string as hex?
Something like  `printf("%X\n", uuid.c_str());`

The output of below code.

```
500E00
A1A2
```

I think it's printing the pointer from `.c_str()` as a hex number.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string uuid = "\241\242";
  
  printf("%X\n", uuid.c_str());
  
  for(int i=0; i < uuid.size(); i++)
  {
    printf("%hhX", uuid[i]);   
  }  

}
```

Comment: I have always used a loop.  There is no print format specifier for treading a C-String as a hex string.

Comment: @CGi03 this is an english speaking site....

Comment: Nothing I can think of that won't either be harder on the eyes or brain. I'd write it once and stick it in a function for use later and to keep the grunt work out of sight.

Comment: You'll have to format to a temporary string then print that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to use ONE printf("%X") to print all the characters in the string as hex?

No.

> Is there a way

You can write your own `printf` with your own specifier that will do whatever you want. You might be interested in `printk` used in linux kernel for inspiration, I think that would be `%*pEn` or `%*ph` or `%*phN`.

On glibc you can add your own format specifier https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html .

Comment: Interesting and clear take on how to get `printf()` to do something new: "write your own `printf`."